# Silverlight Tookit chart makup in xaml fails

Tags: silverlight, xaml, toolkit

While "designing" a chart, I faced a couple of problems which I have yet been unable to solve.
The chart as it is now: http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=10595

1) I want the line of the "AreaSeries" to have the same style as the “LineSeries”. As you can see in the image, it has no style at all :|. Most likely it has something to do with:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:AreaDataPoint">
```

being incorrect, though I cannot find the correct way to do it... Is it possible at all to give the line and datapoints of a "AreaSerie" another layout, or is the only way to do so by creating another lineseries with the same datapoints as the AreaSeries?

2) When I set a minimum for the Y-axis, via script:

```
(this.chart1.Axes[0] as LinearAxis).Minimum = UsersMin;
(this.chart1.Axes[1] as LinearAxis).Minimum = CumulativeMin;
```

It will cause the lines to not showup at all :| (even if I set it to “1”, and the lines are above 1). How can i set a minimum and keep my graphic?

3) Is it possible to put a text in front of a dynamic value in the ContentControl?

```
<ContentControl Content="Users: {TemplateBinding DependentValue}" />
```

Above code does not work, for it thinks {TemplateBinding DependentValue} is just a text, and not a code to be replaced with the data… Is it possible to place a text in front of a databinding? and ifso, how?

The XAML code is attached below.

Thank you!

JB

```
        <toolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="0" />
            </Style>
        </toolkit:Chart.LegendStyle>

        <toolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </toolkit:Chart.TitleStyle>

        <toolkit:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>
            <Style TargetType="Grid">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#AAFFFFFF" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </toolkit:Chart.PlotAreaStyle>

        <toolkit:Chart.Axes>
            <!-- Y-Axis custom range -->
            <toolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="Yusers"
                Orientation="Y"
                Title="Users"
                ShowGridLines="True"
                Foreground="#FF000088"
                FontSize="15" />
            <toolkit:LinearAxis x:Name="YCumulative"
                Orientation="Y"
                Title="Cumulative"
                Foreground="white"
                FontSize="15" />
        </toolkit:Chart.Axes>

        <!-- Daily data -->
        <toolkit:AreaSeries
            x:Name="Daily"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Date}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Daily_User}"
            DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=Yusers}">
            <toolkit:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:AreaDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF001188" />
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />

                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:AreaDataPoint">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                            <ContentControl Content="Users:" />
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}" />
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="#7F0011BF" Fill="Azure"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:AreaSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </toolkit:AreaSeries>

        <!-- Cumulative data -->
        <toolkit:LineSeries
            x:Name="Cumulative"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Date}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Cumulative_User}"
            DependentRangeAxis="{Binding ElementName=YCumulative}">
            <toolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:LineDataPoint">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="black" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False" />

                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:LineDataPoint">
                                <Grid x:Name="Root" Opacity="1">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <StackPanel Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                            <ContentControl Content="Cumulative Users:" />
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding DependentValue}" />
                                            <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding IndependentValue}" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Black" Fill="Azure"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:LineSeries.DataPointStyle>
        </toolkit:LineSeries>
    </toolkit:Chart>
```